# Работа с вложенными курсорами в Oracle через ODP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

Вылетает ошибка при работе с вложенными курсорами в Oracle ODP.NET.
Можно ли как-то это исправить используя ODP.NET?

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=5;"))
{
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "with v_t as (select 1 from dual) select cursor(select * from v_t) c from dual";
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    //вылетает ошибка
}
```

Сообщение об ошибке:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetOraDbTypeEx(Int32 i)
   in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader..ctor(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr[] opsSqlCtx, IntPtr opsDacCtx, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, OpoDacValCtx* pOpoDacValCtx, MetaData metaData, Int32 resultCount, CommandBehavior commandBehavior, Hashtable safeMapping, String commandText, Int32 freeOpsSqlCtx, Boolean bFetchSizePropertySet, Int32 intialLobFS, Int32 internalLobFS)
   in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   in Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
   in ConsoleApplication4.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Если подобный курсор выдается из процедуры (sys_refcursor), ошибка та же самая.

Версия ODP.NET: `64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4)`.

**UPDATE**

С драйвером от devart работает корректно.

Comment: обязан ли курсор дружить с DataReader? Я в своей практике возвращал курсоры через out parameter и ExecuteNonQuery или DataAdapter.Fill

Comment: Можно и через out parameter, но ExecuteNonQuery вылетает с той же ошибкой. DataAdapter - это обёртка. я думаю, и он слетит... :(

Comment: Хорошо, а что-нибудь работает?

Comment: Э... работает все :) кроме вложенных курсоров...